# Different results of the same operation inside and outside function

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

In `loop()` loop I use following piece of code to get the value from analog input (it works well):

```
int temperatura = (int) odczytajTemperature();
```

Function `odczytajTemperature()`:

```
float odczytajTemperature(){
  return  ((analogRead(termometr)*5/1024.0) - 0.5) / 0.01;
}
```

...but when I try to avoid using this function and I just count the value directly in `loop()` (as below) I get random values.

```
int temperatura = (int) ((analogRead(termometr)*5/1024.0) - 0.5) / 0.01;
```

What is the actual difference between this two pieces of code? Why total size of the whole program is 2 bytes bigger for no function version? Shouldn't it weigh less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem with the casting to (int).

Your function odczytajTemperature() returns a float, all the arithmetic is done as floats, and that's all fine.

But when you do

```
int temperatura = (int) ((analogRead(termometr)*5/1024.0) - 0.5) / 0.01;
```

You are casting the first part to an int

```
(int) ((analogRead(termometr)*5/1024.0) - 0.5)
```

and then dividing your int by 0.01.  That might be a valid thing to do sometimes, but it's different to what odczytajTemperature() does.

This is a faithful replacement for odczytajTemperature():

```
int temperatura = (int) (((analogRead(termometr)*5/1024.0) - 0.5) / 0.01);
```